# Teradata - get tablename and column name with the error message

Tags: sql, teradata

In **Teradata** Is there any way to get column name as well with the error message. For example I have a table

- tablename column1 int,
- tablename column2 timestamp,
- tablename column3 timestamp,
- tablename column4 timestamp,
- tablename column5 char(20)

When i insert a wrong value in a column, it does not return me COLUMNNAME.  **For Example if i insert wrong time it just say 6760 : invalid timestamp** 
but which column is having problem we dont know.

**is there is any mathod to know about it**.

Answer (score 3):

No, a SQL Insert will not return that info.
But when you use a MERGE with LOGGING errors instead you'll get a row in the error table indicating which column caused it (iirc).